# I want to get content of timesofindia website for my native app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to develop a native iPhone/iPad app for TimesOfIndia.

I want to get that news content and images.

How do I get that content ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answers your question.. but it seems like TOI already has an iPhone application..

Check this website: http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/mobileapplist/7404562.cms

If you want to get the news from any website, here are some steps you can use (and I am no expert):

1. Try to use a tool like `wget` to download a url to a file and then parse the html, like so:  `wget -O hindu.html www.thehindu.com` (`wget` is available on linux machines). Parse the html or xml in that file and display the headlines and news on your app. Note that this downloading and parsing is best done on a server which could then be pushed (as data) onto the phones of your users.
2. RSS feed. Get an RSS style feed for the website whose content you want. You can then parse the RSS feed and push that onto the users device.
3. Try to build an aggregator (like `news.google.com`) or use an existing one. That way, you can have stories from multiple sources.

Comment: Not only just timesofindia.. I jus gave u an example.. I want to access only readable content of any website.. whether it is timesofindia or thehindu or wat ever it is.. How to get that content?